# Scroll left to right and right to left using mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to scroll on `mouseover` using jQuery (jquery-1.7.1.min.js) but unable to scroll. below is my code.

```js
var ele = $('html,body');
var speed = 1,
  scroll = 3,
  scrolling;

$('#up').mouseenter(function() {
  //scroll the element up
  scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
    ele.scrollTop(ele.scrollTop() - scroll);
  }, speed);
});

$('#down').mouseenter(function() {
  //scroll the element down
  scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
    ele.scrollTop(ele.scrollTop() + scroll);
  }, speed);
});

$('#up, #down').bind({
  click: function(e) {
    //stop scrolling
    if (scrolling) {
      //prevents the default click action
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    if (scrolling) {
      window.clearInterval(scrolling);
      scrolling = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.control {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center
}

#up.control {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0
}

#down.control {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20
}


/* no needed: */

#scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 500px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden!imprtant;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroll">
  Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content
  here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here
  and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and
  more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more
  content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content
  here
</div>

<a href="#" id="up" class="control">left</a>
<a href="#" id="down" class="control">right</a>
```

`onmouse` over on left and right need to scroll text from left to right and left to right but It's not working using jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is few issue in your code:

- `ele = $('html,body');` should be the element that you intends to scroll, not the document `<body>` or `<html>`, e.g in your case is `<div id="scroll">...`
- you have to use [.scrollLeft()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) not `scrollTop()` since you are scrolling left and right, not top, down.

I believe this is what you want

```js
var ele = $('#scroll');
var speed = 10,
  scroll = 3,
  scrolling;
 

$('#up').mouseenter(function() {
  //scroll the element up
  scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
    scroll += 0.5;
    ele.scrollLeft(ele.scrollLeft() - scroll);
  }, speed);
  
}).mouseleave(function(){
  window.clearInterval(scrolling);
  scroll = 3;
})

$('#down').mouseenter(function() {
  //scroll the element down
  scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
    scroll += 0.5;
    ele.scrollLeft(ele.scrollLeft() + scroll);
  }, speed);
})
.mouseleave(function(){
  window.clearInterval(scrolling);
  scroll = 3;
})
```

```css
.control {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center
}

#up.control {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0
}

#down.control {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20
}


/* no needed: */

#scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 500px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden!imprtant;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroll">
  Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content
  here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here
  and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and
  more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more
  content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content here Content here and more content
  here
</div>

<a href="#" id="up" class="control">left</a>
<a href="#" id="down" class="control">right</a>
```